# SQL difference between two days in hours per day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have input: '2017-02-02 11:00:00' and '2017-02-13 15:00:00'

I want to know the difference in hours between these days, but there is a twist: I need to know the hours for each day.

the result would look something like

---

```
'2017-02-02', '13'
'2017-02-03', '24'
...
'2017-02-13', '15'
```

---

If it was only hours then I would use DATEDIFF, but assuming the twist I have no idea how to start. I would appreciate any idea.

ps: there can be different inputs, for example '2017-02-02 11:00:00' and '2017-02-02 15:00:00'

Comment: should the result for 2017-02-13 be 15?

Comment: join on generate_series( ?..

Comment: thanks, fixed to 15, brain had stackoverflow %) so missed that

Comment: it's just example, I will have multiple different dates, between which i have to find difference

Comment: @VaoTsun um, what's that? I probably don't know what u suggest

Comment: if anyone is curious: i have user login and user logout times, so i need to find out which days he was active.

Comment: @Sarief Gordon and vkp explained already :)

Comment: @VaoTsun I've seen, thank you =) the question was asked before the answers showed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `generate_series` to generate all the datetimes with an interval of 1 hour between the start and end dates. Then you can group by the date part to get the number of hours worked each day.

```
select dt_time::date,count(*) as hours_by_day
from (select generate_series('2017-02-02 11:00:00','2017-02-13 15:00:00',interval '1 hour') as dt_time
     ) x
group by dt_time::date
order by 1
```

Comment: this looks like what i need! it's strange why it returns 16 for last day, but i can figure it out with clear head

Comment: @Sarief it returns 16, because `generate_series()` includes both ends, so it will have a rows on `2017-02-13` from `00:00:00` to `15:00:00` (which counts as 16 rows). Actually, you need to call it with `generate_series(:start, :end - interval '1 hour', interval '1 hour')`

Comment: @pozs or with '2017-02-13 14:59:00' :)

Comment: @Sarief of course, but if start and end comes from user input, a subtraction like `:end - interval '1 hour'` is easier.

Answer (score 1):

One way uses `generate_series()` and some arithmetic:

```
with dates as (
      select gs.dte, $date1 as dte1, $date2 as dte2
      from generate_series(date_trunc('day', $date1), date_trunc('day', $date2), interval '1 day') gs(dte)
     )
select gs.dte,
       (case when dte1 > gs.dte and dte2 < gs.dte then 24
             when date_trunc('day', dte2) = gs.dte then 24 - extract(hour from dte1)
             else extract(hour from dte2)
        end) as hours
from dates;
```